# An array passed to a function gives nan elements (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a function that takes in an array and defines a new array made up of a subset of the original array.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
double * subarray(double *array){
       double *sub= new double[100]; 
       for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
         sub[i]=array[i];
       }
    return sub;
}
int main(){
  double *x=new double[100];
  double *y=new double[10];

  for(int j=0; j<100; j++){
     x[j]=sin(j*3.14/2.0);
  }
  y=subarray(x);
  for(int k=0; k<10; k++){
     cout<<y[k]<<endl;
  }
return 0;
}
```

When I run this code some of the elements of the sub array come out as nan.

Comment: Lot of memory leaks

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector` rather than arrays? And why manual memory management (`new`/`delete`)  rather than smart pointers? This code looks sooo 1998'ish..

Comment: Are the values of `x` `NaN`s as well?

Comment: Looks fine and [seems to work fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b49f18c202b1a666) (apart from the memory leaks). Did you forget to recompile something?

Comment: Your example runs fine and doesn't produce any NaN in `y`. Consider using standard containers like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: And stop using `using namespace std`. `endl` is also not required here. `'\n'` is faster.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius `\n` is not portable.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie Can you please elaborate on that? OP's code is printing on a standard output stream, not to a file stream.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie `cout << endl` is defined as `cout << '\n' << flush`

Answer (score 0):

calling subarray is creating a new double[100] then passing that back out. But it's a completely separate array to y = new double[10]. Whenever you call "new" it's making a new thing, separate to all other "new" things. y gets the address of the "new double[100]" but it loses track of the address of the "new double[10]" you made in main, which is a memory leak. If you're going to return a pointer to an new'ly allocated item, start the pointer that's going to store it as a nullptr, and call "delete" or "delete []" when you're done, depending on whether it was a "new[]" thing or just "new".

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
double * subarray(double *array) {
    double *sub = new double[10]; // don't allocated more than you want to use
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sub[i] = array[i];
    }
    return sub;
}
int main() {
    double *x = new double[100];
    double *y = nullptr; // don't set this if you're going to overwrite it

    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        x[j] = sin(j*3.14 / 2.0);
    }
    y = subarray(x);
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        cout << y[k] << endl;
    }

    delete [] x; // if you make new things, delete them afterwards
    delete [] y;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't get any NaNs when I run this, but you are allocating a lot of memory that never gets set, inside the function. You're allocating 100 spaces but only writing to 10. This isn't necessarily an error, but it's not efficient.

Comment: That works too. Code formatter chokes if used after a list.

Comment: You're not wrong, but it would be much better to use smart pointers rather than manual memory management.

Comment: I think people learning the language should at least know what's going on under the hood, then pick the tools they use. So we could throw a smart pointer in there that hides what's going on ... but in that case we just have more people who don't know how memory leaks work. if people are educated about manual memory management then they can make an informed choice about e.g. smart ptr vs shared ptr, because they have some knowledge of how constructors and destructors work, and scope.

Comment: think about if someone was only shown to use a smart_ptr, what happens when their smart pointer goes out of scope but they e.g. copied the address? Now they're referencing de-allocated memory and not know wth is causing intermittent crashes in their program, because nobody ever educated them about proper lifetime of data management to understand what a smart_ptr is about.

Comment: What is the code sample in your answer meant to illustrate? It retains many of the mistakes of OP's code, and introduces undefined behaviour  (`y` only has 10 valid entries, OP output 10 but you changed it to output 100).

Comment: e.h. thanks M.M, i made some edits to the code but it seems the edits didn't save, thanks for alerting me. It was actually identical to the original OP's code and didn't have the edits I'd mentioned in the text.

Comment: e.h. this is weird I did edit this is Visual Studio but now the code is different to what I have in my editor ... ?